# Retaining the value of a variable in Perl

Tags: javascript, perl

I've a GUI front-end (HTML and JavaScript) a Perl back-end. On clicking a certain button on the home page of the front-end, the Perl back-end receives a specific argument. So this argument leads to change of value of a variable (`$checkInfo`) which is then given back to the GUI. The GUI now pops up a message which displays `$checkInfo` and on closing the pop-up, another page (say page 2) opens. On page 2 is a certain button which emails `$checkInfo` to a certain email address.

The problem I'm facing is that `$checkInfo` is equal to `""` on page 2. On page 1, the back-end returns `$checkInfo = something` to the GUI but that value is lost when I go to page 2. I've tried declaring $value as `state $checkInfo` but that doesn't work either. I use `$checkInfo` only in the `main()` function.

In the code, all you need to know is that `preSubmitCheck::autoSubmitCheck` return the value such that `$checkInfo->{rc} != 0` and in the first iteration `$mode ne 'ticket'` but `$mode eq 'ticket'` in the second iteration. In the second iteration, I need the value of $checkInfo to be the same as the first iteration value.

Perl code:

```
my $username = defined param("username") ? param("username") : undef;
my $action = defined param("run_type") ? param("run_type") : undef;
my $cit_suite = defined param("cit_suite") ? param("cit_suite") : undef;
my $buildroot = defined param("buildroot") ? param("buildroot") : undef;
my $site = defined param("site") ? lc(param("site")) : undef;
my $branch = defined param("branch") ? param("branch") : undef;
my $hw = defined param("hw") ? param("hw") : undef;
my $variant = defined param("variant") ? param("variant") : undef;
my $num_runs = defined param("num_runs") ? param("num_runs") : undef;
my $justification = defined param("justification") ? param("justification") : undef;
my $mode = defined param("userAction") ? param("userAction") : undef;
my $jobID = defined param("jobID") ? param("jobID") : undef;
my $cancel_type = defined param("canceltype") ? param("canceltype") : undef;

    state $checkInfo;
    my $error;
    my %rtn = (
           rc => 0,
           message => "All is well."
           );

    if($mode ne "ticket") {
        $checkInfo = preSubmitCheck::autoSubmitCheck($site,$username,$num_runs);
    }
    if(defined $checkInfo && $checkInfo->{rc} == 0){
        my $target = 1;
    }
    else {
        if($mode eq "ticket"){
            $error = $checkInfo->{message};
            my $rtnFromTicket = sendTicket(
                username => $username,
                cit_suite => $cit_suite,
                action => $action,
                buildroot => $buildroot,
                site => $site,
                branch => $branch,
                hw => $hw,
                variant => $variant,
                num_runs => $original_num_runs,
                justification => $justification,
                errorMessage => $error
               );
            $rtn{rc} = 2;
            $allMessage .= " Your job couldn't be automatically submitted: ". $error;
            $allMessage .= " Email info: ". $rtnFromTicket -> {message};
            $rtn{message} = $allMessage;
            print "00delimiter00";       # use as a delimiter to split from useless print information, and make the front end got the json data.
            print to_json(\%rtn);
            exit $rtn{rc};
        }
        else{
            $error = $checkInfo->{message};
            $rtn{rc} = $checkInfo->{rc};
            if($rtn{rc} == 6) {
                $allMessage .= " Your job couldn't be automatically submitted: ". $error. " You can schedule your run or open a ticket with the SMOKES team.";
            }
            else {
                $allMessage .= " Your job couldn't be automatically submitted: ". $error;
            }
            $rtn{message} = $allMessage;
            print "00delimiter00";       # use as a delimiter to split from useless print information, and make the front end got the json data.
            print to_json(\%rtn);
            exit $rtn{rc};
        }
     }
```

GUI code:

```
var query = "username=<% $ARGS{username} %>";
if(Mode=="all"){
    query += "&run_type=Presub_smoke";
} 
else {
    query += "&run_type=CIT" + "&cit_suite=" + document.getElementById("citsuite").value;
}
query += "&buildroot=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("buildroot").value);
query += "&site=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("remoteSite").value);
query += "&branch=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("branch").value);
query += "&hw=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("hwtype").value);
query += "&variant=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("variant").value);
query += "&num_runs=" + document.getElementById("num_runs").value;
query += "&justification=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("justification").value);
query += "&userAction=" + encodeURIComponent(action);
var submitFcts = new Array();
submitFcts[3] = "updateSubmitInfo";
submitFcts[4] = "return_request";
makeUserRequest2("<% $CGI_form_path %>", query, submitFcts, "");
```

I hope this suffices for answering my question. Thanks!

Comment: You need boil your huge amount of code down to a minimal example that exhibits the problem, and then post that example.

Comment: Tip: `my $username = defined param("username") ? param("username") : undef;` can be shortened to `my $username = param("username");`

Comment: @ikegami thanks I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state` only preserves the value of a variable within a single process. When running as CGI, there's a new process for each HTTP request.

If you want to store state across requests, you will need to persist it somewhere that survives across requests -- for instance, by storing it in a cookie, in a session, or in a database.

Comment: I wanted to avoid cookies and databases. Is there any other option?

Comment: So I implemented cookies in one scenario but I'm hitting an error. I added an extra line in the cgi: `my $CookieMessage = defined param("CookieMessage") ? param("CookieMessage") : undef;`  and another extra line in the GUI code: `query += "&CookieMessage=" + encodeURIComponent(document.cookie);` but when the email goes out through PERL, `$CookieMessage` turns out to be empty

Comment: I also noticed that when I read the cookie in the GUI, it gives me the correct value along with some other unnecessary values. `document.cookie = returnedResult["message"]; alert(document.cookie);`

Comment: Okay I could solve my first issue. Turns out I was inserting the statement in the wrong place. But I still don't understand why I get extra information like `s_nr=1476866212523; username=nikhilh; ` in the cookie value

Comment: Okay solved the second issue as well. Turns out I wasn't deleting the previous cookies so they kinda got appended. Thanks @duskwuff for pointing out that cookies are the only way to go :)